# React calling card text from Mongodb string and is not seeing line breaks

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am calling a string from mongodb and placing in a card body like this:

```
                    {this.state.news.map(item => (
                        <Card
                            title={item.headline}
                        >

                            {item.description}

                        </Card>
                    ))};
```

all I get on page looks like a giant block of solid text. I have tried various `/n`  `<br/>` and `<br />` all to no avail.

After some suggetions I tried adding back the `/n` to the string and `<pre>` tags like this..

```
                    {this.state.news.map(item => (
                        <Card
                            title={item.headline}
                        >
                            <div className="storyText">

                                    <pre>
                                        {item.description}
                                    </pre>

                            </div>
                        </Card>
                    ))};
```

and the matching css

```
.storyText{
  white-space: pre ; 
}
```

but either one of those breaks my grid completely and wrecks the page (in different ways of course).

screen cap:
[capture of card with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsUJ.gif)

Comment: Can you give an example of what `item.description` looks like?

Comment: @Nick added screen shot of card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only concerned about paragraph and line breaks, I have solved this issue by splitting by paragraphs, mapping over those paragraphs, and then splitting by line breaks. The following code give an example of how this can be done. For simplicity, you can break it out into its own component.

```
<div>
  {item.description.split("\n\n").map((paragraph, i) => {
    return (
      <p key={`para-${i}`}>
        {paragraph.split("\n").map((line, j) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={`line-${j}`}>
              {line}
              <br />
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </p>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

I put together a quick codesandbox demo showing this in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-butterfly-b2lu7).

Comment: this looks cool. Just to be clear (i am just a student probably trying to make a project over his head) I can put everything inside your div tags inside my card tags and just put my passed in prop of  `{item.description}` where you have paragraph?

Comment: That should work! The basic idea is that splitting on "\n\n" will split into paragraphs, and then splitting within each paragraph on "\n" should split out the line breaks in each paragraph.

Comment: hmmm.. no luck. How can post code here to show how i put it. it says the snippet is too long

Comment: Perhaps you can update the codesandbox example I shared and post the link here?

Comment: here is the string from my mongo collection.. 
`"description" : "In a blah blah ones. /n/n Screening blah blah countries). /n The blah. "` neither the single or double /n does anything

Comment: Hmm, seems you could just switch to forward slashes. e.g., `item.description.split("/n/n")`)

Comment: First time using codesandbox, hope this works.  Obviously it doesnt render anything since it is just a snippet from a much bigger return but hopefully you can see the way i put in my  vscode [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-napier-qtyjg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: OMFG!! I had the wrong direction of slashes in the db string! Everything works now. THANK YOU @Nick

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

So what the working code ended up looking like (in case anyone later on is looking for this same problem)...

```
                        {this.state.news.map(item => (
                            <Card
                                title={item.headline}
                            >
                                <div className="storyText">
                                    {item.description.split("\n\n").map((paragraph, i) => {
                                        return (
                                            <p key={`para-${i}`}>
                                                {paragraph.split("\n").map((line, j) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <React.Fragment key={`line-${j}`}>
                                                            {line}
                                                            <br />
                                                        </React.Fragment>
                                                    );
                                                })}
                                            </p>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>
                            </Card>
                        ))};
```